# Which is better? Primitive datatypes or Wrapper classes?

Tags: java, performance

Which approach is better to use for performance primitive datatypes or Wrapper classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From **Effective Java - Joshua Bloch**

Item 49-  **Prefer primitive types to boxed primitives**

> Use primitives in preference to boxed primitives whenever you have choice. Primitive types are simple and faster. If you must use boxed primitives, be careful!
>   **Autoboxing reduces the verbosity, but not the danger, of using boxed primitives**

---

So if your need is not fulfilled by primitives then you use  boxed primitives, Like in  case of [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Answer (score 1):

The choice depends on the need; whether u need primitve or an object. Wrapper classes are there to provide utility methods and also to be used easily in Collections. Depending on your need you should pick from primitives and wrapper classes. The better you chose the lesser will be overheads of autoboxing/auto-unbboxing.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should use `primitive types` unless you need an object for some reason (e.g. to put in a collection). Even then, consider a different approach that doesn't require a object if you want to maximize numeric performance.